# Find last link in <li> element with the same name

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I need to find by xpath link with the same name in < li > element. Here's below my code

### I need to find last < li > element where < a > text  == Schedule_Planning_New

```
<li name="">
<li name="">
<a id="FormElement_linkList_205-46" name="" rel="FormElement_linkList_205">Schedule_Planning_New</a>
</li>
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
<li name="">
```

---

And here's my xpath, it works just when I have one element < li > with this neme, if it's more than one, it's not working:

---

```
session.getPage().clickLinkByXpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/a[contains(., 'Schedule_Planning_New')][last()]");
```

Comment: session.getPage().clickLinkByXpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/a[contains(., 'Schedule_Planning_New')][last()]");

Comment: but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can access the last element in XPath using `last()` in a predicate.

The XPath for your question -

`li[last()][a/text()="Schedule_Planning_New"]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my code is working, there was other problem in my method, I started to use:

```
WebElement webElement = getSession().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        webElement.sendKeys("\n");
```

instead of:

```
.click();
```